# How to get single result in from sql select query! SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

[image: database diagram]

above are the part of my database diagram where i am getting problem!

select columns from 3 table with the help of referencing  from 1 outside table base_table and 3 table .
But Sql displaying a error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >
```

How to resolve this! Is there is any better way of doing this.
I am new to sql and this is the part of my school project

One more thing the base_id from base_table i i will pass through the procedure in C#
The following are the code which giving the error.

```
USE [shangrila]
select 
a.source,a.destination,
b.flight_name,
c.flight_cost,c.flight_seat,c.flight_type,
d.flight_time
from
base_table a,
flight_main_table b,
flight_cost_table c,
flight_timing_table d
where
a.base_id=109 and
b.base_id=109 and
c.flight_id=(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109) and
d.flight_id=(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109) 
go
```

Comment: I would sure hope they're not still teaching the old style joins in schools.

Comment: It looks like you have more than 1 entry in flight_main_table where base_id = 109.  The quick fix would be to add a ' LIMIT 1' to the end of each subquery, but you should probably reevaluate your database structure.

Comment: @Joe did they ever teach joining on subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned up the query a bit, using explicit joins and some more meaningful table aliases. Let's try this:

```
SELECT bt.source, bt.destination,
       fmt.flight_name,
       fct.flight_cost, fct.flight_seat, fct.flight_type,
       ft.flight_time
    FROM flight_main_table fmt
        INNER JOIN base_table bt
            ON fmt.base_id = bt.base_id
        INNER JOIN flight_cost_table fct
            ON fmt.flight_id = fct.flight_id
        INNER JOIN flight_timing_table ft
            ON fmt.flight_id = ft.flight_id
    WHERE fmt.base_id = 109
```

Comment: thanks this works Except two more rows are coming.But that is the problem of data the table have .Once again thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the subquery `(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109)` returns more than one result which is not allowed when using = operator for the subquery's result. You can either use the keywork IN instead of =, or make sure the subquery contains just one result per base_id.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I am extremely confused. Your query could be very easily rewritten to avoid error, by changing the where clause.

```
where
a.base_id=109 and
b.base_id= a.base_id and
c.flight_id= b.flight_id and
d.flight_id=b.flight_id
```

There is no need for  an Inner query.

Comment: -This is also working  fine Giving the same result which suggested by joe in upper post "INNER JOINS"

Answer (score 0):

[SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <tableName>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Comment: There should at least be some ordering clause or you never know for sure which value you'll get back.

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to you that the subquery

```
select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109
```

is returning more than one value. This is a problem because you tried to join `c.flight_id` to it using `=`, which means it will try to select one row from `c` based on the value on the right-hand side of `=`. If you want the possibility of multiple values, you need the `in` keyword. Try changing it to

```
...
c.flight_id in (select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109) and
d.flight_id in (select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109)
...
```

if it *makes sense* for the subquery to return multiple values. If returning multiple values doesn't make sense, maybe it's time to make sure that your data is clean.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a base_id can correspond to more than one flight_id. I don't know your requirements, so I can't say if that's right or wrong.

If you want multiple flight_id's per base_id, then change

```
c.flight_id=(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109) and
d.flight_id=(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109)
```

to

```
c.flight_id IN (select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109) and
d.flight_id IN (select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109)
```

If you really want a unique flight_id per base_id then you'll have to change your model and data.

PS: You can use JOIN!

Answer (score -1):

In postgresql, you can add a LIMIT clause to your inner selects.  That is, change

```
c.flight_id=(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109)
```

to

```
c.flight_id=(select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109 limit 1)
```

or, if you want to match any of the values, you can do

```
c.flight_id in (select flight_id from flight_main_table where base_id=109)
```

Comment: OP has already stated they are using MS SQL Server, not PostgreSQL.